# Placeholder showing instead of image

Tags: html, image, placeholder

THE HTML:

```
<div class="content-middle-right">
<img src="images/roof-replacement.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

THE CSS:

```
.content-middle-right img
{
    height: auto !important;
    width: auto !important;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

THE images FOLDER:

```
roof-replacement.jpg
```

I can't find anything wrong with that code. Yet, every browser is showing a placeholder instead of the image. I even tried renaming the image and nothing worked.

Help!

Comment: You probably need to provide more details (the whole app structure, where is html file, where is image folder, etc.), but what about  this `<img src="/images/roof-replacement.jpg" alt="" />` ?

Comment: Hmm that's odd. Perhaps check the network tab to see what path is being requested?

Comment: I'll check the network tab. Also, thank you, but adding the forward slash didn't help either... truly weird.

Comment: The network tab inspection shows it's drawing from the exact location the image is in... however, it shows a comment after the closing tag ==$0

Comment: Can you check file extention. Sometimes you need to connect according to him in cases ".jpg, .JPG, .JPEG".

Comment: file extension is okay... the weird thing is, I got the original file to render... it must be in the css somewhere... thank you.